# Compression And Decompression

Tags: c

Using C language
I've compressed a string like-> `aaaabbbbbbccccc` into `a4b6c5`, now I want to decompress `a4b6c5` into `aaaabbbbbbccccc`. I've tried but I'm unable to do this decompression. Please help me out guys.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void compress(char*stng);

int main(){
    char stng[50000];
    printf("Enter the String :");  
    scanf("%s",stng);
    compress(stng);
   return 0; 
}

void compress(char*stng)
{  

    int i=0,count=0;  
    char c=stng[i];  

    while(stng[i]!='\0')
    {  
        if(c==stng[i])
            count++; 
        else
        { 
            printf("%c%d",c,count);  c=stng[i];  count=1;  
        }
        i++;  
    }

    printf("%c%d\n",c,count); 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable and properly indented.  You also need to show your attempt at the decompression part and details what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question about code should contain human readable code.

Comment: Where is your decompress function?

Comment: You should show your attempt at decompression function... The code you show contains nothing about decompression.

Comment: Decompression code is incorrect and incomplete and i've no idea how to do

Comment: Read the character and its length: print that many characters, move on to the next. It's a simple version of [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: Weather Vane I've tried but i'm not getting correct output

Comment: You should post the code that doesn't work - the complete program. It's like going to the repair shop without your car and saying "it does not work, why not?" You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  Consider "111222333", that will result in "132333", which is then ambiguous w.r.t. decompression, and could be interpreted as a string of 32333 '1's or many other combinations.  If you have tried something that does not work, show that code.  Showing the code that works is entirely pointless.

Comment: Saquib, please change your code to have only 1 semicolon per line. ie: add a return after each semicolon. Also, if you just do as @hyde has asked and *show all your code* and the *results of your output* I will answer your question for you. I've upvoted it. Aside from hiding your attempts instead of sharing them with us, it's a good question I think and is nice to see as a practice "compression" approach to get me thinking. There are solutions to all of the possible problems, such as those by Clifford. Solving them just requires some knowledge, thought, and skills, and maybe some peer review.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void decompress(const char* code)
{
    while(*code)
    {
        char c = *code++;   // Get the letter to be repeated
        int rep = 0;
        while(isdigit(*code))
        {
            rep = rep*10 + *code++ - '0';  // Get the number of times to repeat the letter
        }
        char set[rep];
        printf("%.*s", rep, memset(set, c, rep));  // Print letter [c], repeated [rep] times
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char* code = "A4B5C6";
    decompress(code);   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you will never need to have a numeric embedded in the string, this will work.  I just did it as old string/new string, but you can adapt it however works best for you.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    char            szOldStr[] = "a5b11c6";
    char            szNewStr[128];

    int         iStrLen;
    int         iNumChars;
    int         iOldIndex;
    int         iNewIndex;


    iStrLen = strlen(szOldStr);
    iOldIndex = 0;
    iNewIndex = 0;

    while (szOldStr[iOldIndex])
    {
        // Look for a number, which would represent a compressed character
        if (isdigit(szOldStr[iOldIndex]))
        {
            iNumChars = atoi(szOldStr + iOldIndex);
            // Memset one less character, because we already moved one 
            // into the new string
            memset(szNewStr + iNewIndex, szNewStr[iNewIndex - 1], 
                   iNumChars - 1);  
            iNewIndex += iNumChars - 1;

            // Advance past the number
            while (isdigit(szOldStr[iOldIndex]))
                ++iOldIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not a number, so just move the character to the new string
            szNewStr[iNewIndex] = szOldStr[iOldIndex];
            ++iNewIndex;
            ++iOldIndex;
        }
    }

    // Put a null at the end of our new string
    szNewStr[iNewIndex] = '\0';

    // Show what we created
    puts(szNewStr);
}
```

`

Comment: Best not to answer a badly framed question until it has been "fixed".  Moreover this is unnecessarily over-complex.  The `compress()` function in the question always generates strings of the form `<char><count>...` even when the character is not repeated.  Your solution handles `<char><char>...` sequences also.  Even if that were not the case it remains over complicated.

Comment: @Clifford, regarding: `Best not to answer a badly framed question until it has been "fixed"`, I disagree, especially when the asker of the question is a new user and treating them poorly is just going to drive them away. I prefer those who just try to help as able, as @JohnG did.

Comment: For anyone else wondering (like me), what `sz` means in many of the variable names here, `sz means "string of characters, terminated by a null character" (z stands for zero).` (from Tomcat, here: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?83718-What-does-the-sz-in-string-variables-mean). It is part of "Apps Hungarian" notation; see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation.

Comment: @GabrielStaples : Encouraging a new user to improve their question (or answer) is not "treating them poorly". All I an recommending is to hold off until the OP has responded to valid comments on the question. Several time he was asked not unreasonably to post the code of the failed attempt, and has willfully refused to do that. We can only guess at the reasons for that.